# Beginner's Guide to Sustainable Living

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

As a new member of the site, it occurred to me that someone just starting out with trying to live sustainable would not have a readily accessible way of finding out where to start on our site. I'm sure there are plenty of good questions out there for people who are new to sustainable living (the practice, not the site), so I thought a meta repository collecting these questions in one place (maybe even ordering them with the most helpful to getting started at the top?) would be a good idea.

A Community Wiki answer is probably best so we can make lots of small adjustments.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks for setting this up.

Comment: This is great! I just came here for the first time because the subject interests me, but I didn't know how the site ran, especially compared to the other sites where I'm most active. I always check out meta when I first join a site looking for guidance as a beginner so I can be responsible if I vote, or post. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction to Sustainable Living

- [What is the definition of "sustainable"?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5638)

### Reducing one's footprint

- [How do I determine what my biggest personal impact on global warming is?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1003)
- [How do I estimate my personal ecological footprint?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/91)
- [What life-style decision can I make to reduce my carbon footprint most efficiently?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/4532)

### Transportation

- [Are electric cars as environmentally friendly as we think they are?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/612)
- [How to drive to be the most fuel efficient](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/486)
- [Impact of various travelling options](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/93)

### Domestic Issues

- [What form of electrical lighting has the smallest energy-footprint?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/881)
- [What’s the best strategy for turning off CFLs that will save energy but not reduce lifespan so much](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/54)
- [Should I reuse or recycle Ziploc bags?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/489)
- [What is the most sustainable way to dispose of shoes?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/729)
- [Does a dishwasher save water in the long term?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/842)
- [How can I manage my fridge's contents better?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/822)

### Composting

- [Why should I compost?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/158)
- [Is it feasible to compost in an apartment in a city like New York?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/7)
- [Why shouldn't meat be placed in my compost pile?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/38)
- [Are mouldy kitchen scraps okay to compost?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/472)

### Outdoors

- [What is the least environmentally damaging way to start a fire?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/836)